# How can I add a line break to each row in my returned table?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, fs, nightmare

I am working on a web scraper and a table successfully prints, however the formatting of the table is terrible.

I've tried a few things before now

```
1) const people = [...peopleList].map(personEntry => personEntry.innerText + '\n")

2) const people = [...peopleList].map(personEntry => personEntry.innerText).join("\n")

3)  .then(result => fs.writeFile('testfile.csv',JSON.stringify(result + "\n"),'utf8', function(err) {
```

I am pretty stumped, I think the solution *may* involve a loop and appending it but I am not 100% positive.

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false  })
const fs = require('fs');


nightmare
  .goto('https://www.google.com/')
  .type('#lst-ib', 'datatables')
  .click('input[value= "Google Search"]')
  .click('.rc >.r > a')
  .select('select[name="example_length"]',"100")


  .evaluate(function() {
    const headerFields = document.querySelectorAll("#example thead tr th")
    const peopleList = document.querySelectorAll("#example tbody tr");
    const people = [...peopleList].map(personEntry => personEntry.innerText)
    const header = [...headerFields].map(headerEntry => headerEntry.innerText)

    return {
      log: header,
      list: people
    }
  })

  .end()

  .then(result => fs.writeFile('testfile.csv',JSON.stringify(result),'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('File not saved or corrupt');
    } else {
      console.log('your file is saved')
    }
  }))
  .catch(error =>{
    console.error('fail')
  })
```

***Update** if I open the file in a CSV previewer, this is what I see. I would like name, position, office, age, start date, salary on one row, and then all the returned people (with their names offices etc) returned with their own row.

[image: shows all elements on the same row]
[image: What the csv looks like right now]
Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show a sample value of  `peopleList` ?

Comment: @JeremyLee I added what the csv looks like right now , I will use regex to fix the look of it ,but i am confused about why it won't add each person to its own line)

But one returned value might be
`Name      |   Position    | Office    |  Age | Start Date  | Salary 
Airi Satou  Accountant    Tokyo       33    2008/11/18    60,000`

currently, they should be in an array like the following `[airi,accountant,tokyo,33,2008/11/18,60000]`

Comment: people is all 1 large array and the fields (name position etc) is another smaller one.

Comment: So it looks like it's a Tab Separated Values table. In which case you can replace `\t` with `,` and then `.join` them all with `\n`

Comment: really we need a sample JSON to go off of to be honest with an expected output. It looks like you've got nightmare right, but you're identifying your problem and output wrong.

Comment: @RobertMennell would it be 
    const people = [...peopleList].map(personEntry => personEntry.innerText).replace(REGEXGOESHERE).join('\n') ??

Comment: you don't need to spread into a new array. `.map` returns a new array. Just avoid side effects: `const people = peopleList.map(entry => String(entry.innerText).replace(REGEXGOESHERE)).join('\n')`

Comment: with `[...array].map(...)` you're actually creating a new array by looping over the previous array and then looping over it. You should only ever `[...array]` if you want to clone an array without changing any indexes or values since it's the same as `array.map(a => a)`

Comment: Oh, I think I had an issue because It was previously a nodelist and I used the spread operator to convert it - so I should map the nodelist ! Thanks !

Comment: Ah then you might need to spread if it's returning a nodelist and not an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176603/discussion-between-jason-harder-and-robert-mennell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some incorrect parsing and string manipulation happening in this code but it's a pretty easy fix:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
const fs = require('fs');


nightmare
  .goto('https://www.google.com')
  .type('#lst-ib', 'datatables')
  .click('input[value= "Google Search"]')
  .click('.rc >.r > a')
  .select('select[name="example_length"]', "100")

  .evaluate(function () {
    const headerFields = document.querySelectorAll("#example thead tr th")
    const peopleList = document.querySelectorAll("#example tbody tr")

    const people = Array
      .from(peopleList)
      .map(entry => entry
        .innerText
        .replace(/\t/g, ',')
      )
    const header = Array
      .from(headerFields)
      .map(headerEntry => headerEntry
        .innerText
      )
      .join(',')

    return ([])
      .concat(header, people)
      .join('\n')
  })

  .end()

  .then(result => fs.writeFile(
      './testfile.csv',
      result,
      'utf8',
      function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('your file is saved')
      }
    )
  )
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err)
  });
```

First we change the error handler to a more realistic example that will throw us to the same .catch statement every time and can accept a debugger break.

Next we change the write file to write the raw string so it will actually output a CSV, not a JSON string(which will cause everything to be on the same line)

Finally we change the evaluate callback to transform the nodeList(s) to Array, transform then, and eventually join them all with newlines.

The only issue you might run into is a timing issue so some wait statements might be exactly what you want.

Comment: So maybe I should literally tell the program to wait a certain amount of time for the response to ensure it is consistant ?

Comment: possibly yes. It's really helpful if the page navigates

Comment: Seems like execution timeout fixes the issue where the script didn't work 100% of the time. Default it waits 30 seconds now it is longer.
`const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false , executionTimeout: 100000})`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a template literal, which seems to work with this short loop. In your case you may want to try:

```js
const people = [...peopleList].map(personEntry => {`${personEntry.innerText} \n`})
```

Example Loop:

```js
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
  console.log(`This is ${i} times through \n More Text On Next Line`) 
}
```